# Как разбить по папкам ресурсы drawable

Tags: android, android-resources

В общем, в проекте в папке **res/drawable** скапливается много ресурсов и трудно найти потом то, что нужно. Попробовал просто раскидать ресурсы по созданным мною папкам, но они потом не находятся через `getResources().getDrawable()`

Вопрос: каким образом можно разбить ресурсы по папкам внутри папки **res/drawable** ?

Comment: Просто давайте Вашим файлам говорящие имена. Никаких проблем не будет

Comment: это само собой, но даже если имя говорящее его в списке еще нужно заметить, если бы было все по папкам было бы удобней, я знаю что так  можно, в каком то примере видел, но тогда мне это не было нужно,а щас не могу вспомнить где именно..

Comment: Я Вам с уверенностью могу сказать, что подпапки в drawable делать нельзя

Comment: хм... а в папке layout?

Comment: С layout аналогично)

Comment: То, что вы видели в примерах, то это разные версии ANdroid Studio, раньше такое было и я тут с вами согласен, это удобнее, сейчас полный хаос в ресурсах, но на саму работу приложения точно не влияет и зачем вам искать это всё я тоже не знаю, могу лишь сказать с полной уверенностью, что папки там могут отображаться, но при этом у вас должна быть одна и та же картинка, но для разных разрешений и имя должно быть одинаковое

Comment: @BORSHEVIK вы наверное говорите о папках  типа drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi

Comment: @KirillStoianov, о них самых, это было удобно, сейчас всё в куче и просто приписки есть к отдельным картинкам

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, если про них, то они как были так и остались, просто вы смотрите в режиме Android. Переключите в режим Project и увидите все папки на своих местах.

Comment: @dubok79, Я в курсе этого метода, просто непонятно зачем так сделали в текущей версии

Answer (score 2):

В ранних версиях можно было разбить ресурсы по "Экранам". Вместо каталога `res` будут:

- \res-main\
- \res-screen\%НАЗВАНИЕ_ЭКРАНА%\

В `app.gradle` добавляется:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res-main',
                'src/main/res-screen/login',
                'src/main/res-screen/home',
                'src/main/res-screen/about',

        ]
    }
}
```

Но сейчас этот подход не описан в документации:

- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging
- https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources

Не проверял лично, работает ли этот метод.

Источник: [Структура Android проекта – альтернативный путь](https://habr.com/post/303926/)